# Is there a big difference between using SDK and curl In facebook applications?

Tags: php, facebook, curl, facebook-php-sdk

My facebook application send posts to users, I'm using curl lib to throw posts, But i have a performance problems due to the large data, Someone told me to use facebook SDK, But i want to know is there a big difference in using facebook sdk instead using curl lib ??

Answer (score 0):

Facebook PHP SDK also uses curl. SDK also maintain session and user id in persistent cache.This SDK all the required methods but if you have special case, you should analyse the SDK code and modify it